# Просить чего-то или просить о чём-то?

Tags: падежи

Как правильно: *прошу помощи* или *прошу о помощи*?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта, но с различным оттенком значения.

(попросить) чего, что, о ком-чем и за кого.

1. **чего (при сочетании с существительными отвлеченными или конкретными, но употребленными с оттенком неопределенности). Просить помощи**.Просить прощения. Просить слова на собрании. Просить денег (неопределенное количество).
2. чего (при указании на объект временного пользования, см. дать). Чичиков попросил списочка крестьян (Гоголь).
3. что (при сочетании с существительными конкретными). Просить свою книгу. Просить деньги (определенную сумму, заранее обусловленную). Просить милостыню ему не хотелось (Горький).
4. ***о чем (при назывании объекта в общем виде.). Просить о помощи (ср. просить помощи).*** Просить о скидке в цене. Просить о назначении встречи. Просить о сыне.

> См.: ***Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.***

Comment: Интересно, кто поставил мне - 1 за этот ответ. Похоже, некоторым делать нечего.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, оба варианта возможны. В Викисловаре [написано](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), что просить можно о чём-то. Хотя о первом варианте нет ни слова, он тоже возможен.